# How does Bootstrap work with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, structure

I'm unfamiliar with how Bootstrap is implemented on a web app built on Ruby on Rails. I've been asked to create the front-end ,HTML/CSS for new pages. I strictly have been working with small, static sites so I don't know the way to go about this. I've seen that the CSS files only include the specific code that your page requires?

Does that mean that I will have to copy each component's Boostrap CSS to a separate CSS file for my page?

Comment: The official adaptation of Bootstrap to Rails is [`bootstrap-sass`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) that contains more-or-less clear instructions on how to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose one of the following gems to get all the required components of bootstrap in your rails application:

1. [Twitter Bootstrap Rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails)
2. [Less Rails Bootstrap](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap)

Furthermore detailed info to implement it on pages can be get @ http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/integrating-rails-and-bootstrap-part-1

Comment: i think these are already included as SASS files in the vendor/bootstrap folder?

Comment: yes, it must be if using gems and configured well. You can go through the provided link to implement it on pages

Comment: so i'd have to use something like git for this?

Comment: git? for which purpose?

Comment: You need to add these gems in your `Gemfile` (as described in gem docs on github & blog) and run `bundle install`. You may want to have a basic overview of rails application development: guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html